# Is it possible to hide multiple winforms objects with array?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, I mean I did not code for a while so I forgot like everything. I'm trying to hide three objects with an array to make it easier with one line of code

This is how my code looks now.

```
button1.Hide();
button2.Hide();
button3.Hide();
```

But I tried every method that I could but nothing worked. This is how I think it should work.

```
Object[] Buttons = new Object{button1, button2, button3};
Buttons.Hide();
```

Comment: you can do it via for or froeach

Comment: Buttons[] buttons = new Button[]{button1, button2, button3};  buttons[0].Hide;

Comment: `new List<Control> { button1, button2, button3 }.ForEach(ctrl => ctrl.Hide());`? Personally, I'd rather see them listed out; makes it more clear.

Comment: I think it works Heretic Monkey. Thank you soo much. Make this an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: oneliners tend to be less readable than their "verbose" counterparts (in this specific case it wouldn't even be more verbose to write it all out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you place your buttons in a panel and hide that instead? That will scale to anything else in future too should you choose to modify your UI as long as everything which needs to be hidden is in the same `Panel`?

So instead of doing something like

```
void HideButtons(IEnumerable<Button> buttons)
{
    foreach(var button in buttons)
         button.Hide();
}

...

HideButtons(new[]{ button1, button2, button3 });
```

you can simply call `Hide()` on the containing panel

```
panel.Hide();
```

Comment: I accept Heretic Monkey answer too. It's in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it via for or froeach:

```
List<Button> buttons=
    new List<Button>(){button1,button2,button3};

foreach(var button in Buttons)
   button.hide();
```

or

```
new List<Button>(){button1,button2,button3}.ForEach(item=>item.hide());
```